# python -m spacy.en.download connection refused URLError

Tags: spacy

I'm getting the following error when I try to download the English package for an old version of spacy with the command "python -m spacy.en.download": urllib2.URLError...Connection refused. I'm guessing this command no longer works, and I need to upgrade to a newer version? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below steps.

1.Open cmd using "Run as administrator"

2.Use the command

**pip install -U spacy**

3.To download the English package

**python -m spacy download en**

4.To load it

**import spacy**

**spacy.load('en')**